# how to escape this curl command to be used by LUA os.execute?

Tags: curl, lua, escaping

How would one escape this curl command string to be used by LUA os.execute?

```
curl -u mytokenkey: -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Body\nSecond Line\n  http://goggle.com/ "}'
```

Note: I did look for a LUA library that could be used here but the ones I found were written in c code, as opposed to an easy to use ('require') LUA based library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it in a long string:

```
command=[[
curl -u mytokenkey: -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Body\nSecond Line\n  http://goggle.com/ "}'
]]
```

Comment: good idea - I've tried it but it didn't seem to work - the issue too is I'm not sure how to get the response string back to see it??

Comment: @Greg, use `io.popen` instead of `os.execute`, but that is a separate question.